# Magento - Display payment fee on the order page (admin backend)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

During the checkout process I can use the addTotal method on the address object to add a payment fee to be displayed for the user.

```
$address->addTotal(array
(
    'code'  => $this->getCode(),
    'title' => Mage::helper('payment')->__('Invoice fee'),
    'value' => $fee
));
```

Is there any equivilent on the order/invoice object in the administration backend? If not, how can I display my payment fee on the order page (backend)? I've got the payment fee in the sales_flat_order table.

Comment: Try this : https://magecomp.com/magento-payment-surcharge.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the backend you must provide some sort of block.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <YOUR_MODULE>
                    <file>YOURLAYOUT.xml</file>
                </YOUR_MODULE>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/YOURLAYOUT.xml**

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="invoice_fee" template="YOUR/MODULE/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

</layout>
```

**design/adminhtml/default/default/template/YOUR/MODULE/total.phtml**

```
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Invoice Fee') ?></td>
    <td class="emph"><?php echo $this->displayPriceAttribute('invoice_fee', true) ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I define my XML layout file though? I assume its not etc/config.xml (it didnt work there anyway)

Comment: Updated for a little more clarity. ;-)

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I assume there is a similar solution for the invoice page (backend) and order page (frontend, on the user account page)?

Comment: Frontend orders are similar to the checkout page, but handled by Sales module. I've never attempted the backend invoice part before.